# Terraform wants to change boot_diagnostics to null

Tags: terraform, boot, diagnostics

When running **terraform plan**, the output states to change the value of the boot_diagnostics that are set to *false* to *null*

> ```
>   - boot_diagnostics {
>       - enabled     = false -> null
> ```

In the portal, the boot_diagnostics are disabled.

When running **terraform apply**, the resource has been changed.

> Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 destroyed.

Versions used:
Terraform v0.12.10
+ provider.azurerm v1.35.0

The question is: why is terraform showing that *null* although the state equals the reality in the portal?

Comment: Can you show the full plan output? And could you also edit the question to include the Terraform code as a [mcve] that reproduces this please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this specific situation, but this sort of thing usually results from a provider not fully handling defaults that are inserted by the remote API.

In this case, it seems like the remote system sets `enabled` to `false` if it's not explicitly set, but the provider itself is not aware of that and so when you re-plan it believes it needs to update the argument to set `enabled` back to `null`, which is now Terraform represents an argument not being set at all.

The usual workaround for this situation is to update your configuration to explicitly set the value to the default. For this case, that means explicitly setting `enabled` in your configuration:

```
  boot_diagnostics {
    enabled = false
  }
```

With that set, the provider should see that the remote object matches the configuration and thus not plan to make any change.

Ideally a provider should set a default value for an argument like this where "not set" is not actually a valid value in the remote API, but explicitly setting the value is often a good workaround for situations where a provider is not completely handling the normalization/transforms made by the remote API.